# Extracting vertex coordinates of Polygon obtained using Graphics command

Tags: graphics

I wonder if there is a way to extract vertex coordinates from polygon or SierpinskiCurve which are obtained by using the Graphics command? For example
`Graphics[SierpinskiCurve[2]]`, which produce:
[image]

I know I can right click at those images, choose get coordinates, and check the coordinate one by one by moving the cursor to each vertex. But I wonder if there is a better way to do this? I would like to just get a list of vertex coordinates instead of clicking at each vertex one by one.

Comment: `SierpinskiCurve[2] /. Line[x_] -> x` gives vertex coordinates. Also check `DataRange` option.

Comment: Hi Anjan, is DataRange option only gives us the range of the coordinates? How to get the point coordinates of SierpinskiCurve[2]?

Comment: Does `First@SierpinskiCurve[2]` work?

Comment: In general, given a plot named `p` of a set of lines, use `p // InputForm` to see the data on which the plot is based, and then use the appropriate `Part` command to extract the line endpoints.

Comment: Hi kglr, Yes, First@SirspinskiCurve[2] work! =) Thanks  a lot! Also thanks bbgidfrey 13 for the input. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all =) Below is the result of using `First@SierpinskiCurve[2]`:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
(*#1*)
Graphics[SierpinskiCurve[2]] // Part[#, 1, 1] & // Most
(*#2*)
Most @* First @@ Graphics[SierpinskiCurve[2]]
```

Out:

```
{{0, 0}, {32, -32}, {96, -32}, {128, 
  0}, {160, -32}, {128, -64}, {128, -128}, {160, -160}, {224, -160}, \
{256, -128}, {256, -64}, {224, -32}, {256, 
  0}, {288, -32}, {352, -32}, {384, 
  0}, {416, -32}, {384, -64}, {384, -128}, {416, -160}, {384, -192}, \
{352, -160}, {288, -160}, {256, -192}, {256, -256}, {288, -288}, \
{352, -288}, {384, -256}, {416, -288}, {384, -320}, {384, -384}, \
{416, -416}, {384, -448}, {352, -416}, {288, -416}, {256, -448}, \
{224, -416}, {256, -384}, {256, -320}, {224, -288}, {160, -288}, \
{128, -320}, {128, -384}, {160, -416}, {128, -448}, {96, -416}, {32, \
-416}, {0, -448}, {-32, -416}, {0, -384}, {0, -320}, {-32, -288}, {0, \
-256}, {32, -288}, {96, -288}, {128, -256}, {128, -192}, {96, -160}, \
{32, -160}, {0, -192}, {-32, -160}, {0, -128}, {0, -64}, {-32, -32}}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your effort UnchartedWorks. Now I have several tricks in my sleeve to get the coordinate of vertices of polygon obtained by using Graphics command.